# DevExpress GridView details view collections data

Tags: c#, gridview, binding, devexpress

I was trying to populate a DevExpress gridview with some datas.

Let's say we have two classes :

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectB> Details1 { get; set; }     
    public List<ObjectB> Details2 { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And a form created like that :

```
private List<ObjectA> datas;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Fill data
    datas = ... 

    // Set datasource
    this.gridControl1.DataSource = datas;
    this.gridView1.BestFitColumns();
    this.SetRelation();
}

private void SetRelation()
{
    GridView customPatternView = new GridView(gridControl1);
    customPatternView.Columns.AddField("Name").VisibleIndex = 0;
    customPatternView.Columns.AddField("Description").VisibleIndex = 1;
    this.gridControl1.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("CustomRelation", customPatternView);
}
```

This code is working well but I'm obly able to display Details1 in the details view.
How can I do to display only Details2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need one `GridView` for each detail view.

`gridControl1.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("Details1", customPatternView);`
`gridControl1.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("Details2", customPatternView);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GridControl.ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_ShowOnlyPredefinedDetailstopic) property. If you set this property to `true` then the `GridControl` displays only the relationships that exist in the `LevelTree`. Also, use the name of your child list property as relation name in `GridControl.LevelTree.Nodes.Add` method.
Here is example:

```
private void SetRelation()
{
    var customPatternView = new GridView(gridControl1);
    customPatternView.Columns.AddField("Name").VisibleIndex = 0;
    customPatternView.Columns.AddField("Description").VisibleIndex = 1;
    this.gridControl1.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("Details2", customPatternView);
    this.gridControl1.ShowOnlyPredefinedDetails = true;
}
```